# Centering floating elements

Tags: css, html, css-float

Currently I have the following code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="verna.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <section id="devices">
    <h1>Gruppen</h1>
    <div class="group">
      <h2>Gruppe 1</h2>
      <ul>
        <li class="device">Schalter 1</li>
        <li class="device">Schalter 2</li>
        <li class="device">Schalter 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <h2>Gruppe 2</h2>
      <ul>
        <li class="device">Schalter 1</li>
        <li class="device">Schalter 2</li>
        <li class="device">Schalter 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#devices {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#devices .group {
    background-color: gray;
}

#devices .group ul {
    text-align: center;
}

#devices .group .device {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

... which looks like this:
[image]

But I want that the green `<li>`-elements floats in columns. It should look like this:
[image]

Please note: The number of the green `<li>`-elements is variable, there can be more or less than three elements and there can be more than two columns! I want to order the `<li>`-elements "column-wise" and center them...

Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 4):

The thing that is centering "Schalter 3" is `text-align: center;`. We can fix this by removing

```
#devices .group ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and adding:

```
#devices .group ul {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#devices .group li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

in its place. This centers the text in the li element, instead of centering the li element inside the ul. And it adds the margin to the left to get the indent you wanted.

[Working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sZCMz/1/)

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I am searching for. I want to center the `<li>`-elements column-wise in the center of the page without a fix `margin-left` of 50px. What I need is something like a `margin-left/right: auto` for the `ul`-element, but this does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your html so that each "column" is it's own container (div) which has an appropriate width. Alternatively, if you hate yourself, use a table.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rNKJh/1/)

The trick was to turn the `li`s back into block-level elements so that they could have width.  Then set `width: 40%;` (40% leaves a little room for the 5px margin) and `float: left;`.  Also adding `overflow: auto;` to the `ul` so that it would contain its floated `li`s.